# Salesforce User Timezone reverted back

Tags: lightning-experience, system-admin

I am faced with a problem where I changed the user timezone on 28th Feb,20 to (GMT -04:00) hours.
But today I checked the user timezone and found that it has been reverted back to the previous timezone which was (GMT -07:00) hours.
The user has not made the changes nor any other admin made the change.
My question is there any possible way that Salesforce caused the timezone to revert back and is there any way to get the change history on the day when the timezone reverted back?

Comment: Have you checked the Audit trail for changes to that user record?

Comment: i checked in the audit trail but there is no trail of this incident